# preventDefault not working cycling through <li>s that have been moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider and I've organized it into a `<ul>` with the `<li>`s as the individual items to cycle through. Only the second `<li>` is visible, and if you scroll left, it takes the last `<li>` and removes it, puts it on the front, and vice versa if you scroll right.

Here's the Code Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kGBcr

The slider is on the right side, under "More Influencers." The problem is when I click on the 'follow' link, it changes the CSS and text like I want only until it gets to a `<li>` that has been removed and placed on the other end. It doesn't prevent the default link, and just reloads the page.

Thanks for any help!

**The functions that rotate the slider are on lines 120 and 135. The function that changes the text and CSS background color is on line 78.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you remove an element with `remove()`, it loses its bindings, and you need to re-bind event listeners.

However, if you use `appendTo()` instead to move it, the event listeners will stick around.

Another alternative is using the `detach()` function:

```
var objectWithEvents = $('#old').detach();
$('#new').append(objectWithEvents);
```

Your situation is even worse than just removing, since you're using:

```
html = $('element').html();
newHtml = someEl.append('<li>'+html+'</li>');
```

Around line 127. This makes it even worse because not only you're deleting the element, but taking its html content making it even more difficult to keep event listeners associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that about remove() losing the bindings.